# Monodroid Signature Capture

Tags: c#, android, image, canvas, xamarin.android

Hi everybody I have asked this question before but now I would like to go into more details.

Basically I would like to be able to have a canvas that I can paint onto (with finger movement). I could then save the signature as an image on to the sdcard.

Kind of like the android fingerpaint app, but in monodroid C#.

Any code or links would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out my sample utilizing the Android SDK API samples to draw signature and save it to SDCard: https://github.com/Cheesebaron/MonoDroid.CaptureSignature

You will most likely want to add some error handling, for when External Storage is not available and such. You will also need to handle parsing errors if you add additional values to the string array which are not parse-able to an Integer.